# Wicked pdf, failed to load PDF document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, wicked-pdf

I am trying to implement the gem wicked_pdf . After initial difficulties (fatal error (exception reentered)), I managed to start the server. I set up a pdf with the content "Hello world" for the test, but every time I want to open it, I get a "failed to load PDF document" notification

**Controller**

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "index.pdf.haml",
        layout: 'pdf.html.haml',
        page_size: 'A4',
        disposition: 'inline'
      end
    end
  end
```

**index.pdf.haml**

```
Hello world
```

**config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb**

```
# WickedPDF Global Configuration
#
# Use this to set up shared configuration options for your entire application.
# Any of the configuration options shown here can also be applied to single
# models by passing arguments to the `render :pdf` call.
#
# To learn more, check out the README:
#
# https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/README.md
class WickedPdf
  module PdfHelper
    remove_method(:render)
  end
end

WickedPdf.config = {
  # Path to the wkhtmltopdf executable: This usually isn't needed if using
  # one of the wkhtmltopdf-binary family of gems.
  # exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  #   or
  # exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf')

  # Layout file to be used for all PDFs
  # (but can be overridden in `render :pdf` calls)
  # layout: 'pdf.haml',

  # Using wkhtmltopdf without an X server can be achieved by enabling the
  # 'use_xvfb' flag. This will wrap all wkhtmltopdf commands around the
  # 'xvfb-run' #command, in order to simulate an X server.
  # use_xvfb: true,
}
```

**config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Add new mime types for use in respond_to blocks:
# Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

Link to Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ujt8ANq16SrmSHJk45APMXXxm1l5q5ic/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I downgraded wicked_pdf to version 1.4.0 and I removed:

```
class WickedPdf
  module PdfHelper
    remove_method(:render)
  end
end
```

From **config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb**, and now it works.